# Twilio rest api, sending sms

Tags: php, twilio

I am trying to (and have to) use the twilio [rest api to send sms](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/rest/sending-messages) and not using the helper php library.
Below is my code: The problem i am facing is, its giving me the error that 91xxxxxxxxxx is not a valid phone number. But I am passing the phone number to rest api with '+' prefixed.

I am using the trial account and the number is verified with twilio, and tested using the helper library.

```
<?php
$url = "https://api.twilio.com/2010-04-01/Accounts/MYID/SMS/Messages.json";
$from = "MY_TWILIO_NUMBER without + prefix";
$to = "+91xxxxxxxxxx"; // twilio trial verified number
$body = "using twilio rest api";
$id = "MY_ID";
$token = "MY_TOKEN";
$data = array (
        'From' => $from,
        'To' => $to,
        'Body' => $body,

    );
$post = '';
foreach ($data as $parameter => $value)
{
    $post .= "&$parameter=$value";
}
$x = curl_init($url );
curl_setopt($x, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($x, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($x, CURLOPT_USERPWD, "$id:$token");
curl_setopt($x, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_BASIC);
curl_setopt($x, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post);
$y = curl_exec($x);
var_dump($y);
curl_close($x);
?>
```

The complete dump of curl request

```
string(157) "{"status":400,"message":"The 'To' number  91xxxxxxxxxx is not a valid phone number.","code":21211,"more_info":"http://www.twilio.com/docs/errors/21211"}"
```

It does says wrong number (missing '+') but i am not getting where.

Comment: You attempted to initiate an outbound phone call, but the 'To' phone number you supplied was not a valid phone number. Twilio accepts phone numbers in E164 format (i.e. "+1 format"), or 10-digit US and Canadian numbers with any combination of non-digit separators.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Well was missing something, so finally solved.

here's the code

```
<?php
$url = "https://api.twilio.com/2010-04-01/Accounts/MYID/SMS/Messages.json";
$from = "MY_TWILIO_NUMBER without + prefix";
$to = "+91xxxxxxxxxx"; // twilio trial verified number
$body = "using twilio rest api";
$id = "MY_ID";
$token = "MY_TOKEN";
$data = array (
        'From' => $from,
        'To' => $to,
        'Body' => $body,

    );
$post = http_build_query($data);
$x = curl_init($url );
curl_setopt($x, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($x, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($x, CURLOPT_USERPWD, "$id:$token");
curl_setopt($x, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_BASIC);
curl_setopt($x, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post);
var_dump($post);
$y = curl_exec($x);
var_dump($y);
curl_close($x);
?>
```